# Why is is giving me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in second For loop?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Why is is giving me `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in second For loop?

```
public class Ass1Ques2 {

    void rotate() {
        int[] a = {3, 8, 9, 7, 6};

        int r = 2;
        int[] t1 = new int[(a.length - r) + 1];
        int[] t2 = new int[r + 1];


        for (int y = 0; y <= r; y++) {
            t2[y] = a[y];
        }


        // This loop is giving error
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.length - r; i++) {
            t1[i] = a[i + r];
        }

        for (int f = 0; f <= t1.length; f++) {
            System.out.println(t1[f] + " ");
        }
        for (int n = 0; n <= t2.length; n++) {
            System.out.println(t2[n] + " ");
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ass1Ques2 r = new Ass1Ques2();
        r.rotate();

    }

}
```

I don't know how to fix this error,i think i have given the right length to t2.
I want to internally rotate the array clockwise according to r.

Comment: just use `i < a.length - r` without `=`

Comment: also `f < t1.length` and `n < t2.length` in the two last loops

Comment: Why are you creating two `t1` and `t2` arrays in the first place? And why each of your loops use different name for iterator (`y`, `i`, `f` `n`)? `for(int i=0; ...){..}` declares its own iterator `i` which scope is limited only to that specific loop. So you can reuse that name in each non-nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

You access `a[i+r]`, consider the last iteration of the loop. `i = a.length-r` so `i+r = a.length-r + r = a.length` which is out of bounds.

If you want to rotate the array, I recommend using the modulo (%) operator to compute the new position of an index. So in practice, add the rotation to all indices and modulo over the length of the array to get the new positions.

Answer (score 0):

At the last iteration of the loop, you will be accessing a.length, which returns the entire length of the array starting at 1; which causes an IndexOutOfBounds exception since indices start at 0. In order to fix this, just do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length - r; i++) {
    t1[i] = a[i + r];
}
```

This will prevent the for loop from iterating to the *very* last spot of the array with an equal sign, which would've caused an IndexOutOfBounds exception.